# Symmetry of geodesic equations under the transformation of Christoffel symbols

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, geodesics

I am not asking for a solution of the following problem that appears in my assignment. However, I don't understand the question and I would like someone to **explain** the what the question actually is asking **AND** also **hints for a solution** as in where to look for or what to think in solving this,

> Express the geodesic equation as a differential equation for
> $x^{\mu}(\tau) .$ What is the most general transformation of the
> Christoffel symbols that will leave these equations invariant?

(The question assumes metric compatibility and that the connection torsionfree.) The Christoffel can change if there's a transformation $x\rightarrow\bar{x}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$. Also it can change if $\tau\rightarrow{\tau^\prime}$, via,
$$\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}(x(\tau))\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}=0\tag{1}$$
What transformations are the question asking for (may be both! Or maybe a different kind of transformation for Christoffel symbols altogeher)? How to approach the question?

Comment: Are geodesic equations already preserved under coordinate transformations?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\nabla^{LC}$ denote the [Levi-Civita (LC) connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) on a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$. OP's eq. (1) is the [affine geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) $\nabla^{LC}_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=0$, which is independent of the local $x$-coordinate system for $M$, but depends on the world-line parametrization $\tau$: Eq. (1) holds when the parameter $\lambda$ is [affinely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) related to the arc length $s=a\tau+b$ of the geodesic.

For more information, see my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/126033/2451).