Derivative of line element in general relativity is zero?
The Lagrangian for a point particle in general relativity is
$$ L= -m \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} $$
where $x^\mu(\lambda)$ is the world line of a particle with mass $m$. The world line is parameterized with an arbitrary parameter $\lambda$. The derivative is denoted with $\dot{x}^\mu=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial\lambda}$,
I can derive the equations of motions with the Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\mu}- \frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^\mu} =0.$$
However I only get the desired result (the geodesic equation $\ddot{x}^\mu+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\dot{x}^\alpha\dot{x}^\beta=0$) when I assume that:
$$ \frac{d}{d\lambda} \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} =0 $$
why should this hold?

Some intuition: arc length is parameterized viz. $L=-m\frac{ds}{d\lambda}$, so it's analogous to Fermat's principle giving a straight line viz. $\frac{d^2s}{d\lambda^2}=0$.

Why should $\frac{d^2s}{d\lambda^2}$ be zero? One could have an arbitrary relation $s(\lambda)$?

What have you tried?

In general, there is another term on the rhs, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674564/

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94348/2451 and links therein.

Actually you don't need $\frac{d}{d\lambda} \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} =0$.
Since $$L=\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^ \mu \dot {x}^\nu} $$, $L^2$  also satisfies Euler-Lagrange equations.
So take $L={-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^ \mu \dot {x}^\nu} $.
Now $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\mu}- \frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^\mu} =0$$
This will give
$$\ddot{x}^\mu+ \dot g_{\alpha \nu} g^{\mu \alpha} \dot x^\nu- \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g_{\rho \nu}}{\partial x^\alpha}g^{\mu\alpha}\dot x^\rho \dot x^\nu =0$$
Since $\dot g_{\alpha\nu} =\frac{\partial g_{\alpha \nu}}{\partial x^\beta}\dot x^\beta $. Substitute this equation in previous one and use definition of Christoffel symbols as $$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\rho\nu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\alpha} \left( \frac{\partial g_{\alpha\rho}}{\partial x^{\nu}} + \frac{\partial g_{\alpha\nu}}{\partial x^{\rho}} - \frac{\partial g_{\rho\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} \right)$$ You'll get,
$$\ddot{x}^\mu+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\dot{x}^\alpha\dot{x}^\beta=0$$

Thanks a lot! It's definitively great to know how to circumvent the issue that I encounter. But let's say that I want to stick with the sqrt Lagrangian. Then the additional term must vanish if I chose the proper time as a parameterization of the world line? I currently don't see that $\frac{d}{d\tau}\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}}^{-1}$ should be zero?
